# Select dropdown can only submit once

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've created a webpage with two select dropdowns: one for selecting an aircraft type and another for selecting a pilot seat. The problem I'm encountering is that when I select an option in one dropdown, the content in the other dropdown disappears. I want to display both the basic weight for the selected aircraft type and the weight for the selected pilot seat simultaneously.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

- If I select `Aircraft Type: M503-1` I can see the basic weight for that aircraft type displayed.
- Then, if I choose a `Pilot Seat Type: Captain`, I want to see both the basic weight for `M503-1` and the weight for the `Captain` seat displayed together on the page.

I've tried using session variables to store the values of `$basicWeight` and `$pilotSeatWeight`, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. How can I ensure that both `$basicWeight` and `$pilotSeatWeight` are echoed together based on the selections made in both dropdowns?

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['selectedAircraftID'] = "0";
?>


<!--AIRCRAFT DETAIL TABLE-->
<?php
include 'db.php';      

$aircraftID = '0';
$basicWeight = '0';
$CGArm = '0';
$lat = '0';

if(isset($_POST['aircraftType'])) {
  $selectedAircraftID = $_POST['aircraftType'] ; 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM aircraft WHERE aircraftID = '$selectedAircraftID'";

  $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $aircraftID = $row['aircraftID'];
        $basicWeight = $row['basicWeight'];
        $CGArm = $row['CGArm'];
        $lat = $row['lat'];
      }
    }  
  }  
  ?>
  

<!--Basic Weight ROW PHP-->
<?php
  include 'db.php';

  if (isset($_POST['aircraftType'])) {
    $selectedAircraftID = $_POST['aircraftType'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM aircraft WHERE aircraftID = '$selectedAircraftID'";

    if ($selectedAircraftID == "N/A") {
      $aircraftID = "0";
      $basicWeight = "0";
      $CGArm = "0";
      $lat = "0";
    } else {
      $result = $conn->query($sql);

      if($result-> num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
          $aircraftID = $row['aircraftID'];
          $basicWeight = $row['basicWeight'];
          $CGArm = $row['CGArm'];
          $lat = $row['lat']; 
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    $conn->close();
  }
?>   


<!--PILOT ROW PHP-->
<?php           

  $pilotSeatWeight = '0';
  $pilotSeatLong = '0'; 
  $pilotSeatLat = '0'; 
  include 'db.php';

  if (isset($_POST['pilotSeatType'])) {
    $selectedseatID = $_POST['pilotSeatType'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mainseat WHERE seatID = '$selectedseatID'";

            
      $result = $conn->query($sql);

      if($result-> num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
          $pilotSeatWeight = $row['seatWeight'];
          $pilotSeatLong = $row['seatLong'];
          $pilotSeatLat = $row['seatLat']; 
        }
      } 
    } else {
    $conn->close();
  }
?>  


<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Weight and balance calculation</title>

      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/home.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="aircraft-details-container">
        <div class="aircraft-details-header">Aircraft Details</div>
        
          <table class="aircraft-details-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="aircraft-details-th">DATE</th>
                <th class="aircraft-details-th">AIRCRAFT</th>
                <th class="aircraft-details-th">BASIC WEIGHT</th>
                <th class="aircraft-details-th">C OF G</th>
                <th class="aircraft-details-th">LAT(MM)</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="aircraft-details-td">
                  <input class="aircraft-details-date" type="date" name="selectedDate">
                </td>
                <td class="aircraft-details-td">
                  <form method="POST" id="aircraftForm">
                    <select class="aircraft-select" name="aircraftType" onchange="submitForm()">
                      <option value="-" >N/A</option>
                      <?php
                          include 'db.php';
                          
                          if (isset($_POST['aircraftType'])) {
                            $selectedAircraftID = $_POST['aircraftType'];
                          } else {
                            $selectedAircraftID = "-";
                          }

                          $sql = "SELECT * FROM aircraft";
                          $result = $conn->query($sql);

                          while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc ()) {
                            $aircraftID = $row['aircraftID'];

                            if ($aircraftID == $selectedAircraftID) {
                              $selected = 'selected';
                            } else {
                              $selected = '';
                            }

                            echo "<option value='$aircraftID' $selected>$aircraftID</option>";
                          }   
                      ?>    
                    </select>
                  </form>
              </td>

              <td class='aircraft-details-td'><?php echo $basicWeight ?></td>
                  <td class='aircraft-details-td'><?php echo $CGArm ?> </td>
                  <td class='aircraft-details-td'><?php echo $lat ?> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <!---Passenger Details Table -->

        <div class="passenger-details-container">
          <div class="passenger-details-header">Passenger Details</div>
          <table class="passenger-details-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="passenger-details-th">ITEM</th>
              <th class="passenger-details-th">WIGHT (KG)</th>
              <th class="passenger-details-th">SEAT</th>
              <th class="passenger-details-th">ROW</th>
              <th class="passenger-details-th">SEAT WEIGHT (KG)</th>
              <th class="passenger-details-th">CG ARM (MM)</th>
              <th class="passenger-details-th">MOMENTS LONG (KGMM)</th>
              <th class="passenger-details-th">LAT(MM)</th>
              <th class="passenger-details-th">MOMENTS LAT (KGMM)</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          <!--BASIC WEIGHT ROW -->

          <tr>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'>Basic Weight</td>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'><?php echo $basicWeight; ?></td>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'>N/A</td>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'>N/A</td>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'>N/A</td>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'><?php echo $CGArm; ?></td>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'><?php echo(floatval($basicWeight) * floatval($CGArm)); ?></td>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'><?php echo $lat; ?></td>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'><?php echo (floatval($basicWeight) * floatval($lat)); ?></td>
          </tr>

          <!--PILOT ROW -->

          <tr>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'>Pilot</td>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'>80.0</td>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'>
              <form id="pilotForm" method="POST">
                <select class="select-main" name="pilotSeatType" onchange="submitpilotForm()">
                <option value="-">N/A</option>
                <?php
                $pilotSeatType = "";

                if (isset($_POST['pilotSeatType'])) {
                    $pilotSeatType = $_POST['pilotSeatType'];
                }
                ?>
                <option value="pilotSeat" <?php if ($pilotSeatType === 'pilotSeat') echo 'selected'; ?>>Pilot Seat</option>
                <option value="coPilotSeat" <?php if ($pilotSeatType === 'coPilotSeat') echo 'selected'; ?>>Co Pilot Seat</option>
                <select>
              </form> 
            </td>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'>N/A</td>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'><?php echo $pilotSeatWeight; ?></td>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'><?php echo $pilotSeatLong; ?></td>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'><?php echo (floatval(80) * $pilotSeatWeight); ?></td>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'><?php echo $pilotSeatLat; ?></td>
            <td class='passenger-details-td'><?php echo (floatval(80) * $pilotSeatLat); ?></td>
          </tr>



          <script>

            function submitForm() {
                document.getElementById("aircraftForm").submit(); 
            }
  
            function submitpilotForm() {
              document.getElementById("pilotForm").submit(); 
            }
   

          </script>

          </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: FYI: Your code is open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: Whave have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Also, be warned that your query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: Why not put both fields into the same `<form`? Then, when the form is submitted, both selected values will be submitted to PHP at once. At the moment, you have separate forms each with one value in it, and you can only submit one form at a time

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a little missed up, but I try to answer the main question. You should add 2 hidden input to both your form to handle selected option from another form.

- one hidden input for ID and another seat type in first form.
- one hidden input for ID and another for weight in second form.

So when user change one of form, values will be saved on other form hidden inputs with $_POST. But keep in mind that this can make conflict if users keep changing select values or change selects at the same time !

Better way should be using jQuery $.post, Ajax or even XMLHttpRequest. This way you can dynamically update forms and values without any conflict. If you need more details, choose your way and let me know which way you want to go.

Comment: Sure, anytime :)